# Unable to locate the crash origin

Tags: ios, swift, crash

Help me understand this crash, unable to locate the origin of this crash
This crash log is obtained from the appstore.
It is not specific to any version or device. It is happening on all the form factors

```
MAIN THREAD - CRASHED

libsystem_kernel.dylib
__pthread_kill
libsystem_c.dylib
abort
libc++abi.dylib
abort_message
libc++abi.dylib
demangling_terminate_handler()
libobjc.A.dylib
_objc_terminate()
TestApp
MSCrashesUncaughtCXXTerminateHandler() MSCrashesCXXExceptionHandler.mm:160
libc++abi.dylib
std::__terminate(void (*)())
libc++abi.dylib
__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*)
libc++abi.dylib
__cxa_throw
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_exception_throw
Foundation
-[NSString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:]
TextInput
-[TIDocumentState(StateTransitions) documentStateAfterReplacingText:withText:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl setDocumentStateForAutocorrection:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue performTaskOnMainThread:waitUntilDone:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardTaskEntry execute:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl setDelegate:force:]
UIKitCore
-[UIInputResponderController _reloadInputViewsForKeyWindowSceneResponder:]
UIKitCore
-[UIInputResponderController _reloadInputViewsForResponder:]
UIKitCore
-[UIResponder(UIResponderInputViewAdditions) reloadInputViews]
WebKit
-[WKContentView(WKInteraction) _hideKeyboard]
WebKit
-[WKContentView(WKInteraction) _elementDidBlur]
WebKit
WebKit::WebPageProxy::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&)
WebKit
IPC::MessageReceiverMap::dispatchMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&)
WebKit
WebKit::WebProcessProxy::didReceiveMessage(IPC::Connection&, IPC::Decoder&)
WebKit
IPC::Connection::dispatchMessage(std::__1::unique_ptr<IPC::Decoder, std::__1::default_delete<IPC::Decoder> >)
WebKit
IPC::Connection::dispatchIncomingMessages()
JavaScriptCore
WTF::RunLoop::performWork()
JavaScriptCore
WTF::RunLoop::performWork(void*)
CoreFoundation
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopDoSource0
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopDoSources0
CoreFoundation
__CFRunLoopRun
CoreFoundation
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GraphicsServices
GSEventRunModal
UIKitCore
UIApplicationMain
MAMSwift
MAMSwift.cmarRealUIApplicationMain(Swift.Int32, Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Int8>?>, Swift.String?, Swift.String?) -> Swift.Int32 Application.swift:10
TestApp
MAMSwift.cmarHookedUIApplicationMain(Swift.Int32, Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.UnsafeMutablePointer<Swift.Int8>?>, Swift.String?, Swift.String?) -> Swift.Int32 ApplicationSwiftHooks.swift:34
TestApp
main main.swift:12
libdyld.dylib
start
```

Got this crash report from appstore but unable to identify the origin of it.
It's happening across all iOS devices and versions.

Modified the app name to test app

Comment: the problem seems to be in `MSCrashesUncaughtCXXTerminateHandler`. i am developing in react native ios and this crash happens ONLY on several devices

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a bug in text replacement during autocompletion.

Check your code that deals with text fields, text views and the like.

Here is the part of your log that makes me think so.

```
Foundation
-[NSString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:]
TextInput
-[TIDocumentState(StateTransitions) documentStateAfterReplacingText:withText:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl setDocumentStateForAutocorrection:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrection:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:executionContextPassingTIKeyboardCandidate:]
UIKitCore
-[UIKeyboardImpl acceptAutocorrectionForWordTerminator:]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Can you please elaborate on that.

When I'm trying to use a text field in my application, I don't get any auto suggestions.

Comment: I added the relevant parts of your log.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty big chances that you got crash in

> func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn
> range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool

looks like that when user typing some symbols ant clicks full word in top view with variants you have crash in some string function based on idexes